# Problems in building ear with Maven

Tags: maven, ear

Iam trying to build ear with maven.common core and web are built coming to ear its throwing error :unable to generate default application.xml
Unable to read articraft of type test-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change the scope of some jars as provided instead of compile